Getting "Access denied: No token provided" error when accessing protected routes directly via URL, even when logged in (React, Express, JWT)
I'm working on a web application using React and Vite for the frontend, Express for the backend, and MongoDB as the database. I have several protected routes, such as /employees and /clients. These routes require the user to be logged in and authenticated via a JWT token.
Problem:
When I navigate to these routes using links on the webpage, everything works fine if I’m logged in. However, if I try to access these routes directly by entering the URL in the address bar, I get the following error:
{"error":"Access denied: No token provided"}


This happens even when I’m logged in, and the token is stored in localStorage. My login logic works correctly, and the token is sent in the request headers when navigating via links.
Backend (Express):
auth.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

// Login route
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (!user) return res.status(400).send({ error: "Invalid credentials" });

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).send({ error: "Invalid credentials" });

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "7d" });
    res.send({ token });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;


authMiddleware.js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  const authHeader = req.header("Authorization");

  if (authHeader && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    token = authHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");
  }

  if (!token) {
    console.log("No token provided");
    return res.status(401).send({ error: "Access denied: No token provided" });
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET);
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Invalid token:", err.message);
    res.status(401).send({ error: "Invalid token" });
  }
};

module.exports = authMiddleware;


Frontend(React)
App.jsx:
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';
import EmployeesPage from './components/EmployeesPage';
import ClientsPage from './components/ClientsPage';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/employees" element={<PrivateRoute element={<EmployeesPage />} />} />
        <Route path="/clients" element={<PrivateRoute element={<ClientsPage />} />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;


PrivateRoute.jsx:
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ element, redirectTo = '/login' }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  if (!token) {
    return <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
  }

  return element;
};

export default PrivateRoute;


What I’ve Tried:

I’ve confirmed that the token is stored in localStorage after login.
I’m setting the default Authorization header in Axios with the token when the app is loaded.
Protected routes work fine when navigating via links within the app

Expected Behavior:
When accessing the URL directly via the address bar, the app should recognize the token from localStorage, send it in the headers, and allow access to the protected routes.
Question:
Why am I getting the "Access denied: No token provided" error when directly accessing the routes via the address bar, even though I’m logged in? How can I ensure that the token is correctly sent in these cases?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

"Protected routes work fine when navigating via links within the app" - because those are then fetched via Axios, right? So that your app can send the token with those requests. But how do you expect Axios to come into play, when you request such a route directly via the URL bar? In that case, there is no client-side coding that would become active first - a request is made to your server, by the browser itself, not your custom coding. So who is supposed to send any Authorization header then in that scenario?

To put it the other way around: if you wanted the browser to automatically add credentials to all requests, using a scheme that involved custom client-side JS to get the token from local storage and add it by configuring Axios was the wrong choice. Use cookies.

Agreeing to the comment by @C3roe.
For the desired functionality, you may need to use cookies, in place of storage objects or localStorage.
Cookies are a form of ambient authority. The server sets the domain attribute specifying those hosts to which the cookie will be sent. The user agent will include the cookies in making HTTP requests when the domain attribute matches with the origin server. These HTTP requests can be for embedded contents like images and videos from other sites, fetch requests, and also top level navigations.
However, Storage object or local storage cannot be included in top level navigations, the difficulty which you experience now.
